# Benefits of "using" block for SqlCommand initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, .net-4.5

I understand the concept of using `using` block when making a connection to sql server from your application, as it will close the connection as soon as it goes out of scope and saving us time to write `try catch finally` blocks.

But my question is, Is there any benefits of using `using` when initialization a `SqlCommand` normally I would do something like:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.City", con);

        con.Open();

        DropDownList1.DataSource =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "City";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

But what possible benefits I can get by putting SqlCommand initialization in a using `block`?

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.City", con))
    { 
        con.Open();
        DropDownList1.DataSource =  cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "City";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

All the material I have searched online talks about the connection being closed as soon as it goes out of scope, Yes I understand that but putting SqlCommand in using block will it make it any more efficient or not?

Any advice or pointers are much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see this clearly when looking at the source code.

This is the implementation of [`SqlCommand.Dispose`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,53ad9885e5a8fc48):

```
override protected void Dispose(bool disposing) 
{
    if (disposing) 
    {
        _cachedMetaData = null;
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

As you can see, this doesn't do much. But, when looking at [`base.Dispose`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/Component.cs,ec402748f4bd1220,references):

```
public void Dispose() 
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

`SqlCommand` inherits from `DbCommand`, which in turn inherits from `Component`. `Component` implements a [*finalizer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which means that the object will not get disposed once no one is referencing it, as it still has a reference to the [*finalizer queue*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268525/what-are-the-finalizer-queue-and-controlthreadmethodentry).

When you wrap `SqlCommand` with a `using` statement, the most important part of it is that its base class (Component) calls [`GC.SupressFinialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which removes the reference to the finalizer queue and lets the object be collected once the GC kicks in.

That is why `SqlCommand` implements `IDisposable`, and should be disposed.